# ubuntu 18.04 shows new folder above removable usb

Tags: directory

When I create a new folder, it is shown above removable USB or volumes.
How can I fix that?
If there is a way to show all devices on menu bar please tell me.

```
mkdir 'new folder'
```

[image: new folder picture]

Comment: Please avoid combining different questions about unrelated problems in the same Question. You can always create a new question as long as it's on topic and not already answered.

Comment: ok, i am sorry. i will edit it